Dynamic text inserted to Teams Adaptive Card (Json)
I am currently making a Power Automate flow for Approvals, which at the end posts an Adaptive Card to Microsoft Teams that details the steps before something was approved. I've also made it so that it posts the comments made by the approver at each step, which it gets from a SharePoint list using the Get items actions.
This is inserted to the JSON code as
                   {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "@{items('For_each_4')?['Comments']}",
                            "wrap": true,
                            "horizontalAlignment": "Center",
                            "size": "Small"
                        }

Where I add the quotation marks and Power Automate inserts the comment as
@{items('For_each_4')?['Comments']}. Here For_each refers to each item I get from the Get items action.
My issue is that, depending on what the comment contains, this won't work. If a word is put into quotes, it will break the two quotes that are already there. If the comment starts a new line, that won't go through either.
I've noticed that the raw output of the Get items action contains the text in the appropriate format, so \n before new lines and \ before quotation marks, but when I reference it, it will return the regular text.
Is there a way to either get the raw output or somehow convert the text back into a JSON readable format?
I know I could try to use the replace() function on the string to replace new lines with \n or quotes with \" myself but that doesn't feel like a very satisfying solution, and I'm not even sure if having multiple replace functions for every eventuality of what the comment might contain is realistic.

Can you provide an example of the SP item json so we can have a play? Much easier to give you an answer when working with the exact data that’s causing the problem.
